# Where is Naga Sadow buried?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

**Where was the great Sith Sorcerer Naga Sadow buried?**

In KotOR, Revan visits his tomb on Korriban to retrieve his special weapon (the Poison Sword, I believe) but I don't recall if his body or casket is ever shown. Three centuries later, The Emperor's Wrath desecrates the tomb by order of Darth Baras and retrieves Sadow's ancient lightsaber. During the cut scene, the Wrath moves the lid on the casket and there's a skeleton in there complete with Sadow's traditional headdress. He reaches inside and grabs the lightsaber lying next to the body.

However, according the Golden Age of the Sith comic books and the Time Line videos that were released just before SWTOR, Sadow was exiled to Yavin IV, where he lived to the end of his days. Jedi Ovair and his apprentice Gynt visited the tomb there as well. So where was Naga Sadow really buried and why does he have two tombs?

Were the Sith on Korriban during the Cold War just unaware that Sadow was in exile on Yavin IV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sadow was buried on Yavin IV.** He did, however, previously construct a tomb for himself on Korriban.

That said, you do seem to have uncovered a continuity error, although it's not *quite* as glaring as it would seem on first blush.

Sadow ruled the Sith from [Korriban](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Korriban), their ancestral homeworld (sort of...); during this time, like many Dark Lords both before and after him, he had a tomb constructed for himself among the others in the [Valley of the Dark Lords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Valley_of_the_Dark_Lords). (After all, it takes time to build these things, and who wants to trust that the treacherous nerferder apprentice who slays him will build one in his honor posthumously?)

However, at the end of the [Great Hyperspace War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Hyperspace_War), with the Republic having destroyed his fleet around Korriban and defeated him, Sadow fled to Yavin 4. There he built himself [a new temple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Temple_%28Yavin_4%29), and placed himself in suspended animation in a tomb therein -- although the nature of said "suspended animation" seems to be more along the lines of "actually dead, but his spirit still haunts the place", as both (known) [subsequent](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/4400_BBY) [encounters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_to_Yavin_4) were with his spirit only.

Given his intended tomb on Korriban, it's not entirely implausible that he would have placed some of his most precious items in his tomb there -- items that would no longer be available to him following his defeat and hasty departure therefrom at the end of the war, and which could remain there to be found by others later on. (Given that he was fighting -- and losing -- a war at the time, however, I find it questionable he'd have interred his most powerful weapons there...) His body, however, would not have been there -- that's just a simple continuity error, unless someone for some reason put another body in Sadow's tomb, complete with Sadow's headdress (as you describe it, anyway, I've never gotten that far in KOTOR myself).

Comment: Building his tomb before dying makes a lot of sense, since pharaohs in ancient Egypt did the same.

If it's a simple continuity error, then I can let it pass. I thought that one of the Masters at the Academy might have placed a fake corpse in Sadow's tomb as part of the exercise for students to break into his tomb or something.

Comment: @Jamil Yup. It's also consistent with the fact that when he got to Yavin 4 he had his Massassi followers immediately begin constructing a new one. I suppose it's possible someone in the intervening years moved his body to Korriban from Yavin 4, or placed a fake one there, but I can find no reference that indicates anyone has done that.

Answer (score 0):

Naga Sadow buried was in Yavin 4. He fled to Yavin because at the end of the Great Hyperspace War, He Knew that He couldn't return to Korriban for His huge Defeat.
So He Self-Exiled himself with His remaining Massassi and then Built a Sith Temple.
The information are wrong In KOTOR about his Remains in the tomb on Korriban, there are only his artifacts. When He went in Suspended Animation is unclear If He survived with his body shape or only his spirit.
He was a powerful sith sorcerer alchemyst so from my POV is Probable that He could survive. Then Freedon Nadd Will Arrive on Yavin after 600 years and the rest is History!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please provide some references for this?